# Qt style sheet background-color always showing black

Tags: c++, qt, colors, stylesheet, qlabel

working on a project in Qt. I have a variable that will be 0-255. 255 needs to be black, 0 needs to be white, and anything in between should be some shade of gray. So I have a square QLabel. I'm trying to set a stylesheet, but I keep getting black no matter what I put in. Here is what my code looks like:

```
QString color = QString("QLabel {background-color: rgb(%1, %1, %1)}").arg(number);

label->setStyleSheet(color);
```

No matter what 'number' is it always shows as black. Note that I am using windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

The code below works using both Qt 4.8.5 and 5.1.1 on OS X, Windows 7 and Windows 8 (32 bit builds on Windows). The label background is darkish gray.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel label("foobar");
    int number = 100;
    const QString style = QString("QLabel {background-color: rgb(%1, %1, %1) }")
                          .arg(number);
    label.setStyleSheet(style);
    label.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. It looks like 255, 255, 255 is white. I thought that would be black for some reason. Silly me.